# HP printer and Adobe Illustrator colours changing on Mac

Tags: printer, adobe-illustrator, scanning

I have got Adobe Illustrator CS3 on my iMac, Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. I recently got a new printer, an `HP Photosmart B110`, product number `CN245B`, serial number `CN1393K1Q405J8`, driver version `HP Inkjet 8 Driver 3.5.2`. For some reason, whenever I press `Print` in the `File` menu in Illustrator it crashes, taking my work along with it. So I have to save it and open it with `Preview` and print it from there. But the colours change. For example, this image:

[image: Français]

([here is the `ai` file](http://cl.ly/1d2t3m3c3S2b3U3j141i))

looks like this after it has been printed (a scan):

[image: Français print]

The two `a` letters are done with a linear gradient with no blending, but it's exactly the same colour.

It does work if I export the `ai` as a `png`/`jpeg` in preview.

What do I do?

Comment: Can you try uninstall Illustrator then repair permission then reinstall Illustrator. Illustrator shouldn't be crashing in the first place. Did you have your printer profile and monitor calibrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple support :
[Crash printing | Illustrator, InDesign | CS3, CS4 | Mac OS 10.7 (Lion)](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/912/cpsid_91254.html)

**Issue**

Printing from InDesign CS3 or CS4, or Illustrator CS3 or CS4 on Apple OS 10.7 (code named Lion) results in the Adobe application crashing. Acrobat 8.x is also installed, or was installed on the system previously.

**Solution**

The following workaround can be applied to get these older versions of Illustrator and InDesign to print on this newer operating system. Remove the following files and back them up:

```
[Hard Drive]/Library/Printers/PPDs/contents/Resources/en.lproj
[Hard Drive]/Library/Printers/PPDs/contents/Resources/Zh_CN.lproj
[Hard Drive]/Library/Printers/PPDs/contents/Resources/Ja.lproj
[Hard Drive]/Library/Printers/PPDs/contents/Resources/ko.lproj
[Hard Drive]/Library/Printers/PPDs/contents/Resources/Zh_TW.lproj
```

**Additional information**

Creative Suite 3.x and 4.x applications were not designed to function under this newer version of the Mac OS, so some issues can affect them. Upgrading to the latest versions of these applications ensures that you achieve maximum compatibility with the new OS.